# Using apply on a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this one.

```
  A B C D E
0 a b c d e
1 f g h i j
2 k l m n o
3 p q r s t
```

What I'd like is to get a dataframe with each column as a list.

```
     0
0 [a, f, k, p]
1 [b, g, l, q]
2 [c, h, m, r]
3 [d, i, o, s]
4 [e, j, p, t]
```

I'd like to somehow apply a function to each column, converting it to a list and placing it in a new DataFrame. However, apply only operates on individual entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.transpose().apply(lambda x: [', '.join(x)], axis=1))
```

Comment: Thank you! However, at the end of all this, I'd like each list to be a list, not merely have one string in a list, which your solution seems to do.

Comment: Managed to figure this out from what you gave me. I simply needed to apply a split function to each string in  the dataframe! :D Thank you!